# How Can I get Difference in table row from last two values in angular 7?

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, angular7

I have a datatable as shown in the image:
[image]

I am adding data using this form:[image]

When I Add Data Using Form, Value In "Reading" Will be Shown Under Reading Column In Table.

Now I want to calculate the difference between newly added value and last value of "Reading" column.

And Want To Show that Difference Under Usage Column.

Here is my code for adding record:

```
 SaveMeterReading() {
    this.ObjMeterReadingModel.OrganizationId = this.AuthMember.OrganizationId.toString();
    this.ObjMeterReadingModel.CreatedBy = this.AuthMember.UserName;
    this.MeterReadingService.SaveMeterReading(this.ObjMeterReadingModel).subscribe(
      response => {
          if(response > 0){
            this.display = 'none';
            this.RefreshGrid();
            this.toastr.successToastr('Successfully Added', 'Success!');
          }
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Err " + error);
      }
    );
```

Code for getting data:

```
GetAllMeterReading() {

    this.MeterReadingService.GetAllMeterReading().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.clients = response;
        this.chRef.detectChanges();
            const table: any = $('table');

            this.dataTable = table.DataTable({
                "order": [],
                "aoColumns": [
                  { "width": "10%","bSortable": false },
                  { "width": "30%"},
                  { "width": "20%"},
                  { "width": "20%"},
                  { "width": "20%","bSortable": false }
                ],
                "lengthChange": false
                // "dom": '<"left"f>r<t>ip'
            });
            this.countno = 'false';
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Err " + error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Service For Getting Data:

```
GetAllMeterReading(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(env.ROOT + "MeterReading/GetAllMeterReading").pipe(
        map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        }),
        catchError((error: Response) => {
            return throwError(console.log(error));
        })
    );
  }
```

HTML for displaying data in table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Reading</th>
                    <th>Usage</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let client of clients; let idx = index">
                    <td>{{idx+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{client.MeterReadingDate}}</td>
                    <td>{{client.MeterReading1}}</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="UpdateMeterReading(client.Id)"><i
                          class="fa fa-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-default ml-10"
                        (click)="showConfirmBoxForDeleteMeterReading(client.Id)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

How can I achieve this in Angular 7?

Comment: why dont you create a service to fetch the specific record from the datatable by index . after the newly added record is saved, before refreshing the grid,access the last records  `recording` and perform your usage logic

Comment: if you can reproduce this on https://stackblitz.com/, then we might be able to show you with working logic

Comment: @dreamweiver I have updated my post with service class function for getting data. please check.

Comment: just `{{idx>0?clients[idx].MeterReading1-clients[idx-1].MeterReading1:''}}`

Comment: @Aamir, current service what you have shared fetches all the record, but you need to have a new service method to fetch a record by the index(the unique numbers on the data table). later you can call this method to fetch the `reading` data from it to perform your usage calculation

Comment: @AamirHalai, or you can use the `Eliseo's` logic in your template directly, which is the simplest logic

Comment: A word of caution: your table seems to have buttons that allow changing how the rows are sorted. If that is possible you need to define how the difference should work in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Eliseo  for your responese, Your Solution Worked For Me.

Comment: Thanks @dreamweiver for your response Eliseos' s Solution Worked For Me.

Comment: Hello all, I have One more Requirement Regarding This,
When Usage is More than 50 then it should become red.
Any Suggestions on that?

Comment: Added code below in answer. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Following will resolve our issue & hope it will help you.

First row: Returning same value of reading. 
Other row: Returning difference of current reading & above row reading.

```
              <tr *ngFor="let client of clients; let idx = index">
                <td>{{idx+1}}</td>
                <td>{{client.MeterReadingDate}}</td>
                <td>{{client.MeterReading1}}</td>
                <td [ngClass]="{'red': idx > 0 && getUsage(idx)}">{{idx>0?clients[idx].MeterReading1-clients[idx-1].MeterReading1:''}}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="UpdateMeterReading(client.Id)"><i
                      class="fa fa-edit"></i></button><button class="btn btn-default ml-10"
                    (click)="showConfirmBoxForDeleteMeterReading(client.Id)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

`css`

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

`Component`

```
getUsage(index): number {
  return (this.clients[index].MeterReading1 - this.clients[index - 1].MeterReading1) > 50;
}
```